# How do I create a dll project with Eclipse Ganymede?

Tags: java, eclipse, project

**Guys;**

How are you doing today? I have to create a dll project on Eclipse Ganymede and I don´t know where to start... (I am a C# guy with VS).

***Can you please indicate me what type of project should I create*** to make a dll on Eclipse Ganymede so I can call the DLL from other Java Project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't create DLLs. Java source code is compiled into class files, which can then be bundled together in a jar file.

In Eclipse, just create a new Java project, and you'll end up with separate bin and src folders by default; I'm not sure if there's any one-click way of creating a jar file from the bin directory, although you can easily do that from the command line using the `jar` utility, or create an Ant build file which you can run from Eclipse.

When you thought you had to produce a DLL, what gave you that impression? What are you going to do with the code afterwards?

Comment: I was thinking in creating a utility library to handle directories, parse files ,etc So i want to be able to call those functions with different clients...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use certain plugin (e.g. Emonic) to start coding in C#. NET with Eclipse. I guess you have the standard distribution, though.

Anyway, I would recommend you to choose VS (Express) instead or MonoDevelop, if you need a free IDE.